# Request endpoint same application Expressjs?

Tags: express, architecture, api-design

I have an endpoint, `/register`. It is the same that a request post to `/user` but `/register` is public and `/user` is private, then I think, what is the correct call the MongoDB model again or make a request to user, and if it is a request to user how to is it, I mean, exists any form of call the endpoint `/user` or only a request?

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    let { body: { user } } = req;
    user.type = 'normal';
    request.post('/user', { user }).end((err, data) => {
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have two endpoints, `/user` and `/register`. `/user` is not open for ordinary users, but perhaps usable for administrators etc. Now you want to wrap the *add-users-functionality* with a `/register` endpoint that deals with user roles etc., to make adding users safe.

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
function addUser(req, res, userrole) {
  User
    .create({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
      email: req.body.email,
      role: userrole,
    }, (err, user) => {
      let response = {};

      if (err) {
        response = responseDueToError(err);
      } else {
        console.log('User created with username:', user.username);
        response.status = HttpStatus.CREATED;
        response.message = user;
      }

      return res.status(response.status).json(response.message);
    });
}

router.post('/user', (req, res) => {  // "private endpoint"
  addUser(req, res, 'admin');
};

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {  // "public endpoint"
  addUser(req, res, 'user');
};
```

So don't create a new request in the register endpoint, but make a separate addUser function that both the private and public endpoint can use.